# Android display nested menu under parent icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have the following very simple `Toolbar` dots menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24px"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/options"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_edit"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:title="@string/edit"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
        </menu>

    </item>
</menu>
```

Looks like this:

[image: expanded submenu]

When I click the dots button, the submenu shows, but it overlaps the dots:

[image: toolbar menu]

How to make it display UNDER the dots? I can maybe do this with a popup menu but it feels like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, in your first definition of the attribute "*showAsAction*" in the item, which has the id **empty**. You need to set the value as "*ifAsRoom*" also like you did in the submenu.

You defined the first item (empty) as **always** and this can overlap the action item with other elements UI in the action bar. Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource) .

Comment: I tried adding `ifRoom` to both items and it's the same. From what I read in the docs - it makes sense to try to show the 3 dots with `always` (always displayed in the toolbar, not in the context menu). However, I do want my `Edit` button to always show in a context menu (so maybe I should define it with `showAsAction=never`). However, I want the context menu to show UNDER the 3-dots icon, not cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style in your `Toolbar` like the following.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" />
```

Now declare the `MyTheme` in your `styles.xml` file like the following.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The key idea is setting the `actionOverflowMenuStyle` which has the following attribute.

```
<item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
```